# specifying the joint distribution as a proof technique

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

The following is a theorem in stochastic process in Pinsky's An introduction to Stochastic Modeling:
[image]

The **proof** starts as the following:
[image]

Here is my **question**:

> Could anybody explain why and how one can freely specify the joint distribution of each $\epsilon(p_k)$ and $X(p_k)$ in order to prove (5.11)?

---

The proof continues as the following. But I don't know how the joint distribution is specified.
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is an error in the Pinsky-Karlin text (which existed in the earlier Taylor-Karlin version of the book). Namely, the specification of $\epsilon(p)$ should be $\epsilon(p)=0$ if $0\le U<1-p$ and $\epsilon(p) =1$ if $1-p<U\le 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic here is that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables for which it possible to place an upper bound on
$|P_X(A)-P_Y(B)|$ that involves the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$:
$$|P_X(A)-P_Y(B)|\le P_{(X,Y)}(C)\tag1$$
and if (1) holds even when we don't specify what that joint distribution is, then the inequality continues to hold when we take the infimum of the RHS over all choices of $P_{(X,Y)}$:
$$|P_X(A)-P_Y(B)|\le \inf_{P_{(X,Y)}}P_{(X,Y)}(C)\tag2$$
Finally we pick a particular joint distribution for $(X,Y)$, say $P^*_{(X,Y)}$. Since the inf of a set is no bigger than any element in the set, we can then assert
$$|P_X(A)-P_Y(B)|\le P^*_{(X,Y)}(C).\tag3$$
The name of the game is to pick a $P^*_{(X,Y)}$ to make the inequality (3) as sharp as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the beauty of the *coupling method*. The left side of the inequality (5.11) depends only on the marginal distributions of $S_n$ and $X(\mu)$. We are free to construct random variables with any joint distribution we please (designed to minimize the right side of (5.11)) so long and we arrange that $S_n$ and $X(\mu)$ have the specified marginal distributions. The idea then is that to make $Pr\{\epsilon(p)\not=X(p)\}$ small we try to make these random variable equal on as large a portion of the sample space as we can, subject to the distributional constraint. Making them both ($\epsilon(p)$ and $X(p)$) functions of a single random variable $U$ is a simple way to do this.