# Bernoulli and Poisson random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm reading the following argument which is related to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1708626/9464):

[image]

I think when $p<1/2$, the statement is not true. Could anybody explain the underlined sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a mistake in the proof (good catch!). The correct definition of $\epsilon(p)$ should be:
$$
\epsilon(p)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $1-p<U\le1$}\\0&\text{if $0<U\le1-p$}\end{cases}
$$
The proof should go through with this revised definition of $\epsilon(p)$: The event $\{X(p)=0,\epsilon(p)=0\}$ is then the same as the event $\{U\le e^{-p},0<U\le1-p\}=\{0<U\le 1-p\}$ since $1-p\le e^{-p}$. Similarly use the inequalities $1-p\le e^{-p}$ and $(1+p)e^{-p}\le1$ to show that $P(X(p)=1,\epsilon(p)=1)$ equals
$$P(e^{-p}<U\le (1+p)e^{-p},1-p<U\le1)
=P(e^{-p}<U\le (1+p)e^{-p})=pe^{-p}.$$